# Неправильный Запрос в  Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql

Вопрос вроде бы и простой,но я не могу понять Почему строк в таблице 500, а если пишешь

```
SELECT count(N_INFO_COLD)
FROM COMPUTATION
```

выдает большое число и только rownum помогает....

Comment: скореее за все у вас именно случай описанный by @Gorets, чтобы наверняка убедится можете сделать сиквенс и в селект добавить test_seq.nextval тогда макс значение этого поля и будет количеством всех записей. хотя я лично б не сомневался в правильности работы оператора count. RTFM !

Answer (score 2):

может всеже строк больше, а на экран выводит только 500, а рядом есть кнопка - показать следующею часть

Comment: нет там непонятно почему-то выводятся после тех строк которые есть в таблице еще десятичные числа, которых в таблице нет.....

Comment: покажи скрин

Comment: А что дает запрос
SELECT count(*), count(N_INFO_COLD) FROM COMPUTATION
?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно в поле N_INFO_COLD имеются значения NULL, которые не считаются оператором COUNT.

Comment: тогда почему больше?)))

Comment: Попробуйте добавить/удалить строку и посмотрите количество (500 - слишком круглая цифра).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
SELECT count(distinct N_INFO_COLD)
FROM COMPUTATION
```

Comment: такое даже не отработает

Comment: А ты попробуй, прежде чем говорить

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй запустить DBCC CHECKTABLE ('YourTable');
Данная процедура доолжна вернуть тебе некие данные о ошибках в таблице, возможно в таблице проблема.